# Adding a new column in SQL corresponding to previous column

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a new column in an existing SQL table (name: mytable) which when a user starts a new project within 20mins, it is consisted to be in the same "timetable"(new column)

Please see the case below:

```
Name        Date/Time
Candance    2018-09-22 11:20:14
Candance    2018-09-22 11:35:12
Jon         2018-09-23 12:12:13
Jon         2018-09-23 12:20:34
Jon         2018-09-23 12:40:54
```

What I would like to get:
note: user has to be the same for each "timetable"

```
Name        Date/Time            Timetable
Candance    2018-09-22 11:20:14  1 
Candance    2018-09-22 11:35:12  1
Jon         2018-09-23 12:12:13  2
Jon         2018-09-23 12:20:34  2
Jon         2018-09-23 12:40:54  3
```

Comment: Select **one** DBMS - either MySQL or PostgreSQL. And specify **precise** server version.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only the tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: @user15289436 . . . If you have interleaved data -- such as John at 12:33:00 -- what would the results look like?

Answer (score 2):

Solution for MySQL 8+

```sql
WITH cte AS (
SELECT *, CASE WHEN name = LAG(name) OVER (ORDER BY name, date_time)
                AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, LAG(date_time) OVER (ORDER BY name, date_time), date_time) < 20
               THEN 0
               ELSE 1
               END new_timetable
FROM test
)
SELECT name, date_time, SUM(new_timetable) OVER (ORDER BY name, date_time) timetable
FROM cte
ORDER BY name, date_time;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c8011bc838b53169d37927a1ae8b401)

Comment: Hi Akina, I just posted an extension of the question, just wondering if you can help out as I loved this answer of yours. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AKina logic is correct.  However, I would phrase it more simply as:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_datetime >= datetime - interval 20 minute
                then 1 else 0
           end) over (order by datetime) as timetable
from (select t.*,
             lag(datetime) over (partition by name) as prev_datetime
      from t
     ) t;
```

I do want to note that in the original data, one user's timestamps are entirely separate from the other users.  The above solution represents the ordering of the *original* rows.  This can get complicated if the data is interleaved.